# Looping a List view crash the app when iterations > 6

Tags: java, android

I have a Listview. I loop through this listview and append text inside textview to a file in sdcard. The problem is that this TextView assignment

```
tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.codigo);
```

crashes after i = 5:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

There is no problem with only 4, 3, 2 or one iterations.

Here is my code

```
public void alertDialogGuardar() {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogo_guardar, null);
            final EditText editText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.nombrefichero);
   
            dialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                            file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/invgreen/"+editText.getText()+".txt");
                            System.out.println("Se elige el nombre de fichero "+editText.getText());
   
                            if (file.exists()){
                                file.delete();
                                System.out.println("Se borra el fichero "+editText.getText());
   
                            }else {
                                try {
                                    file.createNewFile();
                                    System.out.println(file.toString());
                                    System.out.println("Se crea el fichero " + editText.getText());
   
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Log.e("Exception", "Error al CREAR en el fichero: " + e.toString());
                                }
                            }
   
   
                            View v;
                            System.out.println("Se declara vista");
                            TextView tv;
                            System.out.println("Se declara textview");
                            int count = lv.getAdapter().getCount();
                            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   
   
   
                                ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup) lv.getChildAt(i);
                                    //System.out.println("Dentro bucle antes de escribir en posicion "+i);
                                    //v = lv.getChildAt(i);
                                    tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.codigo);
                                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tv.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    EscribeaFichero(tv.getText().toString() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                    //System.out.println("Dentro bucle despues de escribir en posicion "+i);
                                //}
                                /*else{
                                    System.out.println("Dentro bucle en ultima posicion ");
                                    v = lv.getChildAt(i);
                                    tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.codigo);
                                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tv.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    EscribeaFichero(tv.getText().toString());
                                }*/
                            }
   
                            finish();
                            startActivity(getIntent());
                        }
                    });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCELAR",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"cancel is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog=dialog.create();
            dialog.setView(dialogView);
            dialog.show();
            //alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: what is your counter value ? print that before using for loop.

Comment: You should get this information directly from the adapter (`getItem()`), instead; `ListViews` don't immediately create child views for each row; it defers some, until the scroll position gets nearer to them (because they may be off-screen, and there is no need for a `View`).